Why does this function not work within a powershell param block?
I have the following code:
param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$DummyOU, # OU to put dummy devices in.
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$CertTemplate, # CA Certificate template short name used when issuing certs to intune devices.
  [string]$logfile =  "$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("$($PSCommandPath | Split-Path -Leaf)"))-log.csv"
)

"$($PSCommandPath | Split-Path -Leaf)" | Out-File C:\Automation\test.txt
"$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("$($PSCommandPath | Split-Path -Leaf)"))-log.csv" | Out-File C:\Automation\test.txt -Append
"$logfile" | Out-File C:\Automation\test.txt -Append
exit 0

It produces the following output in test.txt:
map-intune-certs.ps1
map-intune-certs-log.csv
-log.csv

I execute the script with the following command line:
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\map-intune-certs.ps1 -DummyOU "Test" -CertTemplate "Test2"

Notice that $logfile is corrupted.
However, this problem does not occur if I remove the mandatory parameters. It also appears the problem does not occur in Powershell v7.4.3 whereas it does occur with v5.1.22621.3880. Why does $([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("$($PSCommandPath | Split-Path -Leaf)")) produce blank output when used in the param block along with the mandatory parameters?


Indeed, you've found a bug in Windows PowerShell (since fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7), which is unlikely to get fixed however, as Windows PowerShell will only see security-critical fixes.

By using [Parameter()] attributes, you're implicitly making your script an advanced one (the explicit way to do that is to place a [CmdletBinding()] attribute above the param(...) block).

The bug manifests when an advanced script is called via powershell.exe, the Windows PowerShell CLI, using its -File parameter: In this case, the reflection-related automatic variables such as the automatic $PSCommandPath variable, $PSScriptRoot and $MyInvocation are unexpectedly not defined (yet) in expressions used to determine parameter default values.



Workaround:
Make the CLI call via the -Command (-c) parameter rather than -File (-f).[1]
# Note the use of -Command, overall "..." enclosure with embedded '...' quoting,
# and exit $LASTEXITCODE to pass the script's specific exit code through.
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ".\map-intune-certs.ps1 -DummyOU 'Test' -CertTemplate 'Test2'; exit $LASTEXITCODE"

Note:

-Command accepts a piece of PowerShell code, which means that the code inside "..." above is parsed as it would be from inside a PowerShell session, which can affect how the pass-through parameters are parsed (not an issue in your case). Use \" to specify pass-through " characters.

-Command also reports only an abstract exit code - 0 (success) or 1 (failure) - based on the last statement executed, unless that last statement is an exit call with a numeric argument, as used above; the automatic $LASTEXITCODE variable reflects the exit code of the most recently executed external program or PowerShell script that terminated via exit with a numeric argument.

For a detailed explanation and guidance re -Command vs. -File, see this answer.



Alternative:

You can (loosely) emulate what [Parameter(Mandatory)] does by using a throw statement as the default value of the parameters you want to be mandatory.

Additionally, you may want to guard against unexpected arguments (something that advanced functions / scripts prevent automatically), by reporting an error if the automatic $args variable (containing the array of arguments not bound to declared parameters) unexpectedly has elements.


Thus, if you define your script as follows (body simplified), you can still call it via powershell.exe -File:
# Do NOT use [CmdletBinding()] here and
# do NOT use [Parameter()] on any of the parameters.
param (
  [string]$DummyOU = $(throw "Missing -DummyOU argument."), # OU to put dummy devices in.
  [string]$CertTemplate = $(throw "Missing -CertTemplate argument."), # CA Certificate template short name used when issuing certs to intune devices.
  [string]$logfile = "$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($PSCommandPath))-log.csv"
)
# Prevent passing of unexpected arguments.
if ($args) { Write-Error "Unexpected arguments passed: $args"; exit 1 }

"[$logfile]"
exit 0

Note that you must use neither [CmdletBinding()] nor [Parameter()] attributes, lest the bug resurface.
Note that all your declared parameter can also be bound positionally, i.e. without placing the target parameter name before the argument; you could only avoid this in an advanced script/function, which is not an option here.

[1] Note that if you specify neither, the behavior differs by PowerShell edition: Windows PowerShell defaults to -Command, whereas PowerShell 7 defaults to -File.
